# How to connect to a semicolumn separated CSV file form ms-access

Tags: csv, ms-access, delimiter

What do I need to add to

```
DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, tableName:="myLinkedTableName", _
    fileName:="c:\myFolder\myFile.csv", _
    HasFieldNames:=True
```

if the fields in `c:\myFolder\myFile.csv` are separated by `;`?

If `DoCmd.TransferText` does not have such option, is there an alternative way to connect to a file as table programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Link the file manually using the wizard. Specify the separator as semicolon.

Save the import specification. Remove the link.

Now, specify the import specification to use when creating a new link:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, tableName:="myLinkedTableName", _
    fileName:="c:\myFolder\myFile.csv", _
    HasFieldNames:=True, _
    SpecificationName:=YourImportSpecification
```

Comment: How do I save the import specifications?

Comment: I understand, this only works as long as the structure of the CSV is unchanged. That is not my situation.

Comment: Oh, then you are in trouble. You may wish somehow to run a search/replace on the file before attempting to link it.

Comment: I'l force my users to use excel files. Thanks anyway.